# load website with Nodejs functions integrated

Tags: rest

I have a little NodeJS server, which an index.html invites me over `serve-static`.

Is it somehow possible that are contained in the index.html functions of NodeJS?

Theoretically, I could of course solve the whole problem with express routes, but possibly there is also another solution

```
var serve = serveStatic(__dirname+"/../Websites", {'index': ['index.html']});

// Create server
var server = https.createServer(options,function onRequest (req, res) {
  serve(req, res,finalhandler(req, res));
})
// Listen
server.listen(443, function(){
    console.log('WebServer running on 443...');
});
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var hello = require('hello');
            console.log(hello.sayHello());
        </script>

        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```